# How to securely backup Jenkins configuration?

Tags: jenkins, backup

I am setuping a Jenkins environment to manage workflows of Python projects. This Jenkins install is running on a Windows 7 machine and I need to backup the Jenkins config to avoid potential loss of work in case of HDD failure (for example).

I tried the [SCM sync configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) but this one is not compatible with the [Subversion](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) plugin I use and caused Jenkins to display only a white screen when I activated it. So it is not usable.

I also tried the [thinBackup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup). It works well but, due to Jenkins being ran as a local service, it is not able to save backups on a network drive (and backuping on the same drive than Jenkins is not very insteresting). You would think that I just have to run Jenkins with a network user, but in this case it would not have sufficient local privilèges.

I am thinking about creating a Batch (or Python) script which could deal with SVN to backup the Jenkins configuration by adapting what is described in [this page](https://jenkins.io/blog/2010/02/10/keeping-your-configuration-and-data-in-subversion/) but I am not very happy to write a SVN account password in a Batch (or Python) script which could potentially be seen by anybody.

So I would know if it exists an other way to achieve this Jenkins configuration backup.
Or at least, does it exists a way to perform svn commands without showing anybody a clear password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues with the SCM sync configuration plugin sadden me, too. What we do with our Jenkins instances, is: we use thinBackup to run regular backups and store them in the default folder on the same HDD. Then we have a daily cron job rsync them with a folder on another HDD. So if Jenkins is running on Windows, you would probably achieve the same using the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) and [cwRsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync), for example.

Comment: After a long period of search and reflection, I think there is no better way to do this for now.